# Where is ADF file on Tango Device?

Tags: google-project-tango

I have a Tango tablet device. So i made a ADF file using Tango Explorer.

I want to export the ADF file to PC from device.

But i cannot find the ADF file.

Please let me know where is the ADF file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to root your device in order to do this. The devices come in a user build and so you'll need to migrate to a user debug build. After you root your device, enter the following commands in terminal to pull your ADFs onto your PC:

```
adb root 

adb shell 

cd /data/data/com.projecttango.tango/files/Tango/ADFs

adb pull /devicedirectory/ ~/localdirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to root your Tango, the [Tango ADF Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.chucknology.tango.adftool) is a good alternative and allows you to export and then share your ADF files with other devices.

Answer (score 0):

They have been moving the location over last two years. As of recently I found the ADF's with

`adb shell ls /sdcard/Maps`